# Java Method is skipping return statement

Tags: java, stack, return

This java method is skipping over a return statement. I was wondering if anybody has encountered this and know of a solution. Whatever the bug is it's very subtle.

```
public GameState getNextGameState() {
    if (player.getLives() > 0) {
        if (!player.isAlive()) {
            System.out.println("checkpoint 1");
            player.setIsAlive(true);
            return new PlayField(width, height, hiScores, player.setCoordinates(width / 2, height - 8),
                    stagePattern, stage);
        }
        System.out.println("checkpoint 2");
        if(++stage > 29)
            stage = 0;

        return new PlayField(width, height, hiScores, player.setCoordinates(width / 2, height - 8), stage);
    }
    return new GameOver(Game.key, hiScores, player.getRank());
}
```

Here is a screenshot with console output to prove it:
[image]

Also, this bug only started happening when I put my gamestates in a stack structure. Here is the code I'm now using for the gamestate transition:

```
public void update() {

    gsm.peek().update();

    if(gsm.peek().finished)
        if(gsm.peek().getNextGameState() == null)
            gsm.pop();
        else
            gsm.push(gsm.pop().getNextGameState());             
}
```

gsm declaration is:

```
public static Stack<GameState> gsm = new Stack<GameState>();
```

Hopefully someone has some insight. Thank you!

Comment: If your "proof" is that it's logging "checkpoint 2" after "checkpoint 1", that's obviously another invocation. Try debugging your code.

Comment: You're calling `getNextGameState` twice...

Comment: Also, PlayField and GameOver both extend GameState

Comment: Well, you can use the debugger to see what's happening. But the most likely explanation is that you have 2 calls to the method, the first one displaying `checkpoint 1` and the second one `checkpoint 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the result of the same call.
You call twice the method here.
The first time it is not alive, the second is alive. So you have the both message in the output.
In a game, the update phase is called in a continuous way.
Just add a `System.out.println` at the beginning of the method (that is before the conditions) and you could have the confirmation :

```
public GameState getNextGameState() {

     System.out.println("enter method");
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. New stack invocation is `gsm.peek().update();

  GameState gs = null;
  
  if(gsm.peek().finished) {
   gs = gsm.peek().getNextGameState();
   gsm.pop();
   
   if(gs != null)
    gsm.push(gs);
  }`

Answer (score 1):

Can you post more code? You are probably calling it twice and it is not skipping over the return. If you really think it is put a break point to assist you with debugging and watch the code run.